# Setting object in http get request

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, http-get, apache-commons-httpclient

I am writing a client side java program for a Pageable Spring data resource
The repository GET API is of the format:

```
public Page<Person> findByCountry(..., Pageable pageable);
```

I have created a pageable request of the format

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 40, new Sort("name"));
```

However, I would like to know how I can set this pageable into my `http client`.
I am using `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`.

I googled a bit and found most links using spring rest controller. Can I not do this by using apache http client? Springs hateoas seems another option. But it would mean adding another jar to my client project. Is it just the question of how to set payload on a request?

Additionally, if there are better approaches let me know. I want to loop through all the pages till the data is exhausted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple.
The mistake I was making was setting an parameters with non default names. Spring's rest api will create a pageable object if you pass correct params (As explained in 'HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers for Pageable and Sort' section of [reference doc for Spring Data Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) )

Pageable will be automatically created if the request has params with given names like page, size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what I am going to suggest is the best approach but this is how I would go about it. Since you cannot have a reference to the Spring dependent object i.e Pageable in your lean client without adding a Spring dependency to your client you may want to send your PageRequest details as HTTP GET query parameters to your HTTP GET API something like this and loop over your technology independent pagewrapper results as shown below.

**API signature**

public PageWrapper findByCountry(..., int page, int size, String sortBy, String sortDirection);

**PageWrapper:**

```
List<T> items;
int currentPage;
int totalPages;
int totalItems;
boolean isLast;
```

**API Code:**

```
Pageable nextPageable = new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(sortBy));
Page<Person> personsPage =  countryService.findByCountry(.., nextPageable);
if(null != personsPage){
  PageWrapper<Person> pageWrapper = new PageWrapper<>();
  pageWrapper.setItems(personsPage.getContent());
  pageWrapper.setTotalPages(personsPage.getTotalPages());
  pageWrapper.setTotalItems(personsPage.getTotalElements());
  pageWrapper.setCurrentPage(personsPage.getNumber())
  pageWrapper.setIsLast(personsPage.isLast());
  return pageWrapper
}
```

**Client code:**

```
PageWrapper page = null;
do {
    Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramMap.put("page", index++);
    paramMap.put("size", size);
    paramMap.put("sortBy", "name");
    page = (PageWrapper) httpClient.get(requestURI, paramMap);
    process(page);
}while(!page.getIsLast())
```